Who are the other two thieves?
In the second season of the animated series Secrets of the Mogwai, Chang asks Sam how many thieves he knows, to which the latter replies "four, including you." One of the others is obviously Elle, from the context of the conversation.
Some obvious possibilities for the remaining two include Greene, who even gets called more or less a common thief (but "knows" would seem a questionable description for someone with whom Sam had about three short conversations and who is dead at the time Sam answers the question); Elle's street urchin gang from Shanghai (but there are more than two of them); or maybe even Sam's grandfather, since "treasure hunter" is basically just a nice way of saying "thief," in the end. Or possibly one of the many people who have tried to kidnap Gizmo. But of course, all of these together are a lot more than two people.
Who are the other two thieves that Sam knows?
